# Resolve Unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

```
vikiboy@BatCave:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-openni-launch 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ros-indigo-openni-launch is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev : Depends: libopenni-sensor-primesense0 (= 5.1.0.41-3+trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

On running sudo apt-get -f install

vikiboy@BatCave:~$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  at dctrl-tools devscripts distro-info-data dput libaudclient2 libaudcore1
  libdistro-info-perl libexporter-lite-perl libio-stringy-perl libmowgli2
  libparse-debcontrol-perl python3-magic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libopenni-sensor-primesense0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libopenni-sensor-primesense0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/300 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,354 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 343931 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libopenni-sensor-primesense0_5.1.0.41-3+trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libopenni-sensor-primesense0 (5.1.0.41-3+trusty1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libopenni-sensor-primesense0_5.1.0.41-3+trusty1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/openni/GlobalDefaults.ini', which is also in package libopenni-sensor-pointclouds0 5.1.0.41.1-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libopenni-sensor-primesense0_5.1.0.41-3+trusty1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help

Comment: try this `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two packages want to write to `/etc/openni/GlobalDefaults.ini`, the `libopenni-sensor-pointclouds0` package and the `libopenni-sensor-primesense0` package. That should not happen, and is an error in the packets. As a somewhat hackish solution, I would try to do a backup of that file, e.g., like this:

```
sudo mv /etc/openni/GlobalDefaults.ini /etc/openni/GlobalDefaults.ini.back
```

then, do the `sudo apt-get -f install`. With a little bit of luck, it will go through. You should then do a

```
diff /etc/openni/GlobalDefaults.ini /etc/openni/GlobalDefaults.ini.back
```

to check whether there are any major differences in the configuration that you need to take care of.